# Preciso apagar a linha que casa com uma palavra no primeiro arquivo e também a do segundo arquivo na sequência. Como faço?

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk, grep

Preciso apagar uma linha inteira através de uma palavra que eu vou definir e ao mesmo tempo apagar também outra linha, mas, agora deve ser noutro arquivo que corresponda a linha do primeiro arquivo. Como no exemplo abaixo:

```
1º Arquivo - Nome.txt           2º Arquivo - Sobrenome.txt

Benedito Amaro                  Texeira
Paulo Souza da                  Cunha
Ricardo Ramos                   Faria
Carlos Eduardo                  Neto
Angelita Gusmões                Filho
Davi Onorato                    Favaro
```

Manualmente apagaria dessa forma aqui:

`sed -in '/^Ricardo/' Nome.txt ; sed -i '3d' Sobrenome.txt`

O que eu preciso saber é um meio de automatizar o segundo comando `sed`, pra eu poder apagar a linha correspondente aquela deletada no primeiro.

Ou seja, preciso apagar duas linhas uma no primeiro e outra no segundo arquivo, ambas, correspondem na mesma **SEQUÊNCIA** e **POSIÇÃO** da linha entre o arquivo NOME e SOBRENOME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ou seja, preciso apagar duas linhas uma no primeiro e outra no segundo arquivo, ambas, correspondem na mesma sequência da linha entre o arquivo NOME e SOBRENOME.

1 - O ideal seria pegar a posição da linha que será deleteda do primeiro arquivo e,

2 - passar pra uma variável (por exemplo: N="4" [número]) para segundo comando `sed $Nd` poder recuperar a posição e executar a tarefa.

Segue o exemplo de como fiz:

## Código - opção: 1

> `awk` - Se eu precisar saber o numero da linha onde foi encontrada a string.

```
C=`awk '{printf"linha ->%d : coluna ->%s\n",NR,index($0,"Ricardo")}' < Nome.txt`
N=`echo "$C" | awk -F '>' '{print $3}' | awk -F '0' '{print $1}'`
sed -in '/^Ricardo/d' Nome.txt ; sed -i "${N}d" Sobrenome.txt
```

Não é o código dos mais bonito .. mas ta feito. Funciona!

Não sei o que acontecerá no caso de mais de um casamento na mesma linha teste aí e nos diga nos comentários. Para o propósito da pergunta esta solução ja ta valendo.

## Código - opção: 2

> `grep` - Se eu precisar saber o numero da linha onde foi encontrada a string.

```
N=`grep -n "Ricardo" Nome.txt | cut -d\: -f1`
sed -in '/^Ricardo/d' Nome.txt ; sed -i "${N}d" Sobrenome.txt
```

Este último é um código minificado, limpo e fácil de decorar.